# What would be the right way to increase cost for Auto Renewable Subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have an app that offers auto-renewable subscriptions and I would like to increase the subscription cost but I'm not sure how to handle existing customers. Let's pretend for a moment that I currently have 100 subscribers who paid $9.99/year when they first subscribed, what would happen if I increase the subscription cost to let say, $19.99/year in the middle of their payment cycle, are they going to be notified before their next renewal date and give them the chance to cancel or it will just auto-renew automatically without letting the user know about the cost increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you increase the price for an existing product, you'll have the option to allow existing users to remain at the current price or increase the price for them as well. If you choose to increase the price for existing users, they will receive a prompt from Apple to opt-in to the price increase or else their subscription will expire.

The cleanest way to do a price increase (or any price change) is **always** to create a new product in App Store Connect. This will make your life way easier when it comes to analytics, accounting, price testing, etc.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot for the good points you made. By the way, RevenueCat rocks!